# Increasing space between title and date (beamer class)

Tags: beamer, spacing, titles

I'm writing my first document in beamer class and I'd like to increase the vertical space between author and date in the title page so that the last one is in the bottom of the page. My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Some title in the middle of the page}
\date{Some date in the bottom of the page}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

If someone could help, I'd be grateful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In my opinion the safest way is to define your own title page and play around with the spacing as you like.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{Some title in the middle of the page}
\date{Some date in the bottom of the page}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
  \vbox{}
%  \vfill
    \vspace{3.5cm}% NEW
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vspace{1.5cm}% NEW
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
%    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
%  \vfill
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can do it by putting \vspace*{} by some adjustment in the argument

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\title{\vspace*{-2cm}Some title in the middle of the page}
\date{\vspace*{-4cm}Some date in the bottom of the page}

\begin{document}

\frame{\titlepage}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This will cause trouble with presentations which use the date and the title in the footline.