# Control placement of fields in title frame of a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, positioning

This code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\title{Big Title}
\subtitle{Small title}
\author{
  Name Surname
}
\institute{
  Excellent University
}
\date{Meeting, January 24, 2018}
\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}
\end{document}
```

produces a title page

[image]

How can I move the `\title` field down by 2cm?
How can I position the `\date` field 1 cm from the bottom?

Comment: You could modify the title page template according to your needs, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/370521/36296 for an example.

Comment: I don't want the fields to be in a colorbox. What to do?

Comment: Set the colour of the boxes to empty, e.g. `\setbeamercolor{title}{bg=}`. Hint: The fields in your example are also in boxes :)

Comment: How can I position a field 1cm from the bottom? It was not apparent from the linked answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changes compared to the default title page are marked with comments:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{title page}{%
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \vskip2cm%<- added
  \begingroup
    \centering
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \vfill%<- added
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vfill%<- added
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \vfill%<- added
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip0cm%<- changed
%    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
  \endgroup
%  \vfill%<- removed
}
\makeatother

\title{Big Title}
\subtitle{Small title}
\author{Name Surname}
\institute{Excellent University}
\date{Meeting, January 24, 2018}

\begin{document}
\frame{\titlepage}

\begin{frame}
    \rule{2pt}{1cm}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How is one sure that the date is 1cm from the bottom?

Comment: @Viesturs The date is only 1 cm from the bottom for the currently shown number of lines. There is some glue between the element to accommodate maybe a two line title, but if the page gets overly full, the date will be pushed down off the page.

Comment: @Viesturs If you'd like absolute positioning, you could try https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398056/36296